# How to embed an image in a cell a table using DT, R and Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

How can I embed an image in a cell that is generated using the DT package so that it is displayed in an app using shiny?

My example is based of this question [R shiny: How do I put local images in shiny tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575241/r-shiny-how-do-i-put-local-images-in-shiny-tables)

The example code below doesn't display the image, but rather just the url.

```
# ui.R
require(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyUI(
  DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')
)

# Server.R
library(shiny)
library(DT)


dat <- data.frame(
  country = c('USA', 'China'),
  flag = c('<img src="test.png" height="52"></img>',
           '<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg/200px-Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg.png" height="52"></img>'
           )
)

shinyServer(function(input, output){
  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(dat)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the `escape = FALSE` in your DT call, as per: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/#escaping-table-content

```
# ui.R
require(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyUI(
  DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')
)

# Server.R
library(shiny)
library(DT)


dat <- data.frame(
  country = c('USA', 'China'),
  flag = c('<img src="test.png" height="52"></img>',
           '<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg/200px-Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg.png" height="52"></img>'
           )
)

shinyServer(function(input, output){
  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(dat, escape = FALSE) # HERE
  })
})
```

[image: Images working with DT]

Comment: At this point in time, it is not working for me. Could that be because of some change in the package?

Comment: @FissehaBerhane Recommend you open a new question with MWE (minimum working example)

Comment: this answer could help for images on the server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47804593/adding-an-image-to-a-datatable-in-r

Answer (score 1):

Minor update from 2021:

```
require(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyUI <- DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')

dat <- data.frame(
  country = c('China'),
  flag = c('<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg/200px-Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg.png" height="52"></img>'
  )
)

#now this is a function
shinyServer <- function(input, output){
  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
    DT::datatable(dat, escape = FALSE) # HERE
  })
}

#minor change to make it runnable
shinyApp(shinyUI, shinyServer)
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your answer to explain what you've changed and why? That will make this a lot more useful to future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

The solution which worked for me was the following:
function was assigned to shinyServer `shinyServer <- function` instead of earlier way of using `shinyServer(function(input,output)`