# Plot shows up in renderTable but not DT::renderDataTable

Tags: r, plot, shiny, dt

I am trying to put a small plot into a `DT::dataTableOutput` in shiny and while I can put a plot into a `tableOutput` with no problem, it doesn't display at all in the DT version.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("data1"),
  tableOutput("data2")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$data1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    dat <- cars[1:5,]
    dat$test <- c("a","b","c","d",
      '<div id="testPlot1" class="shiny-plot-output" style="width: 100px ; height: 100px"></div>')
    dat
  },escape=FALSE)
  output$data2 <- renderTable({
    dat <- cars[1:5,]
    dat$test <- c("a","b","c","d",
      '<div id="testPlot2" class="shiny-plot-output" style="width: 100px ; height: 100px"></div>')
    dat
  }, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
  output$testPlot1 <- renderPlot({
    par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
    plot(cars[[1]],cars[[2]])
  },height=100,width=100)
  output$testPlot2 <- renderPlot({
    par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
    plot(cars[[1]],cars[[2]])
  },height=100,width=100)
  outputOptions(output, 'testPlot1', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: plot expected in red circle]

Comment: for  DT you need the path to be a data uri see this post on how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47804593/adding-an-image-to-a-datatable-in-r

Comment: Interesting. Would this require plotting to png's instead of using renderPlot then?

Comment: yes ypu would have to plot to png and then create the data uri path

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the table is rendered later.

A possibility is to render the plot with `plotOutput` and then to move it to the cell with JavaScript:

```
js <- c(
  "function(){",
  "  var $plot = $('#testPlot1');",
  "  var $td = $('#data1').find('table').find('tr:last-child').find('td:last-child');",
  "  $td.append($plot);",
  "}"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("testPlot1", width = "100px", height = "100px"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("data1"),
  tableOutput("data2")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$data1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    dat <- cars[1:5,]
    dat$test <- c("a","b","c","d","")
    dat
  }, escape=FALSE, options = list(initComplete = JS(js)))
  output$testPlot1 <- renderPlot({
    par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
    plot(cars[[1]],cars[[2]])
  },height=100,width=100)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Here I've selected the target cell by using the fact that it is the last cell of the last row. A more general strategy is to put a `div` with an `id` in the target cell, like this:

```
  output$data1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    dat <- cars[1:5,]
    dat$test <- c("a","b","c","d",'<div id="target"></div>')
    dat
  }, escape=FALSE, options = list(initComplete = JS(js)))
```

and then you can select it like this:

```
js <- c(
  "function(){",
  "  var $plot = $('#testPlot1');",
  "  var $td = $('#data1 #target');",
  "  $td.append($plot);",
  "}"
)
```